# Python - Cross correlation of two signals with NaN inside

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I got two signals S1 and S2 (two arrays of values) and I would like to know if S1 is the same signal as S2 but shifted (Graphic representation would be the same for S1 and S2 but S1 will be moved to the right or the left)

The problem is: My algorythm contains interpolation `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, and this function input NaN values in the arrays.

When I'm trying to correlate S1 and S2 with NaN inside, the correlation array is always `[NaN, NaN, NaN, ... , NaN, NaN, NaN]`

My purpose is :
1) Detect if S1 and S2 are the same signal (if the correlation is above a certain threshold, I'll consider that they are the same signal)
2) If there are, detect the shift between them so I'll be able to remove it

To illustrate my algorythm, I created a simple code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate

norm = np.linalg.norm

x = np.array([np.nan,1,2,3,0,0,np.nan])
y = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])

corr = correlate(x, y)

print(corr/(norm(x)*norm(y)))
```

Here the correlation function is `scipy.signal.correlate` but I tried with np.correlate too and I got the same results

From a stackoverflow post, I tried this way:

```
x = np.array([np.nan,1,2,3,0,0,np.nan])
y = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])

normx = norm(x[~np.isnan(x)])
normy = norm(y[~np.isnan(y)])

maskx = np.ma.array(x, mask=np.isnan(x))
masky = np.ma.array(y, mask=np.isnan(y))

corr = correlate(maskx, masky)
```

But I still got only NaN values..

Is there something that I do wrong ?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

**If any of the signals contains NaN then the retusrn will be all NaNs.**

---

Use this to initially remove the nans and then use the correlation function:

```
x = np.array([np.nan,1,2,3,0,0,np.nan])
y = np.array([1,2,3,0,0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])

x = x[~np.isnan(x)]
y = y[~np.isnan(y)]

corr = np.corrcoef(x, y)

#corrcoef returns the normalised covariance matrix so you want the [1,0] or [0,1] element of this matrix
print(corr[1,0])
#1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm trying to figure out what np.corrcoef returns and why do I prefer this function more than np.correlate, can you explain a bit ?

Comment: The `numpy.correlate` is the Cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences. On the other hand, the `numpy.corrcoef` returns the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficients. You can use whatever measurement you want. In my answer, I just demostrated how to get rid of the NaNs